# error with submitting page using curl..in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, curl

using below command in shell script:

```
DATE="2017/04/18"
curl --data "transactionNumber=12520264&traceNumber=466245&serviceDate=${DATE}" http://isp:7005/ClaimUtility/claimReversal
```

Getting below response:AS ERROR

> ```
>   <p><b>message</b> <u>Request method 'POST' not supported</u></p>
>   <p><b>description</b> <u>The specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource (Request method 'POST' not supported).</u></p>
> ```

what should be the correction required??

Comment: i have browsed too much.. but did not get the answer!! where they using shell script.

Comment: Seems quite an obvious error, you're trying to POST, and the server doesn't support it on that page.

Comment: that means the URL i am using is not correct??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agree with `John Weldon`

endpoint you're trying to post to `http://isp:7005/ClaimUtility/claimReversal` does not support POST requests.

So i have corrected the URL which is supporting POST form
ie.h`ttp://isp:7005/ClaimUtility/claimReversalReversal`

Answer (score 1):

This means that the endpoint you're trying to post to `http://isp:7005/ClaimUtility/claimReversal` does not support POST requests.

You can try using `GET` and the content will be encoded as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` on the url as query params.